# How to set up background-image as style in Django

Tags: html, css, django

I have a simple website that I need to set a background image as a style as below

```
<header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url('static/img/home-bg.jpg')">
```

which is from a sample example site.
I seem to be stuck on getting the above to work in a Django template. I have tried

```
<header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url('{% static "img/home-bg.jpg" %}')">
```

but its not working.

I am using manage.py runserver with static_url and STATICFILES_DIRS set as follows:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MAIN_PROJECT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(MAIN_PROJECT, 'static/'),
)
```

I have my template in **ContainerFolder\homeapp\templates\homeapp\index.html.**
I have put the image files in a toplevel static folder ie in **ContainerFolder\Static\Img** because I want to avail them to all apps.

Comment: What's the rendered output? (Right click -> View page source)

Comment: The rendered output is  as follows:  <header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url('/static/img/home-bg.jpg')">

Comment: OK great. And what's `STATIC_URL` and `STATICFILES_DIRS` ?

Comment: Hi Leistungsabfall I have added the details to the question

Comment: Try changing `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` to `STATIC_URL = 'static/'`.

Comment: Did you include `{% load staticfiles %}` at the top of your html template?

Comment: Yes @yuvi I actually have some css files linked in and the formatting is working ok.Its just the background image that is presenting a problem.

Comment: OK. Try opening the chrome devtools and check (1) on the elements panel, select your header and look at the CSS applied to it. Can you see the background image attribute? Is it supposedly working? (2) check the network panel (open then reload) see if the request for the image is returned. If it is, the problem is with the CSS argument (maybe you need to add `no-repeat` or there's another CSS statement that overrules this one). If it isn't, then the problem is the address. Make sure you're using the correct filename

Comment: Did you solve this problem?